# Recursively Checking for List Uniqueness in Python

Tags: python, list, recursion, unique

I have a list of 100 numbers and I am trying to write a function to determine whether all of the numbers are unique (as they should be). My function is `unique(lst)` and it takes a list as an input and should return True if all the numbers in my list are unique. Oh and False otherwise, an example:

```
>>> unique([1, 2, 3])
True

>>> unique([2, 4, 3, 4])
False
```

I wrote this so far:

```
def unique(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        if lst[0] in lst[1:]:
            return False
        if lst[1] in unique(lst[2:-1]):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

I'm having trouble recursively checking whether the  numbers after lst[0] are unique. Can anyone tell me how to edit my code so it checks correctly?

Comment: `unique()` returns a boolean, so `lst[1] in unique(...)` is not going to work. And why ignore the last item when recursing?

Comment: "CLOSED Topic CLOSED"? If you want to delete your question, there are better ways to do that. In general, though, questions *shouldn't* be deleted if they're high-quality and answerable -- the point of StackOverflow is to build and maintain a generalized, reusable knowledge base other people can search and learn from.

Comment: Note also that terms of service are such that posting content on StackOverflow means the site gets a **perpetual** license to that content. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274757/why-is-deleting-own-posts-consuming-delete-votes for a discussion of guidelines on deleting data; in general, the rule is that a question should only be removed if it of "no lasting value whatsoever". That said, such questions typically are ones that shouldn't have been asked here in the first place. :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want this recursive approach? Much clearer and very much more efficient would be to loop over the list only once and use a `set` to keep track of already seen values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
def unique(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        currentElement = lst[0]
        remaining = lst[1:]
        elementIsUnique = currentElement not in remaining
        recursive = unique(remaining)
        return elementIsUnique and recursive

>>> unique([1, 2, 3])
True

>>> unique([2, 4, 3, 4])
False
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, would you like me to break up the `else` case into a few more lines that are step-by-step?

Comment: Okay I broke it up into a few more steps, hopefully that is more clear.

Comment: Yes, `elementIsUnique` will be a `bool`. And `recursive` will keep calling `unique` over and over until it eventually reaches a length of `1`, unless `elementIsUnique` ever becomes False, then it will return early. You cannot say `return elemtIsunique and return recursive` because you may only `return` 1 time in a function, that would be invalid syntax to write it like that.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to keep recursively moving across the list, you don't need to return a boolean :

```
def unique(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1: # if a single element left, list has unique elements
        return True
    elif lst[0] in lst[1:]: # check if current element is in the remainder of the list
            return False
    else:
        return unique(lst[1:]) # move to next element
```